# Fastest way to Select a random number from each row padded numpy array (excluding the pad) and number of non padded values, using numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a 2D numpy array, each row is padded with (with -1 for the example below).

For each row, I want to pick a random number, excluding the padding, and also get the number of non-padded values for each row, using only numpy operations.

Here is a minimal example. I picked -1 for the pad, but the pad can by any negative int.

```
import numpy as np
numList = [[0, 32, 84, 93, 1023, -1], [0, 23, 33, 45, -1, -1], [0, 10, 15, 21, 24, 25], [0, 23, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0 , 13, 33, 34, -1, -1]]
numArray = np.array(numList)
numArray

array([[   0,   32,   84,   93, 1023,   -1],
       [   0,   23,   33,   45,   -1,   -1],
       [   0,   10,   15,   21,   24,   25],
       [   0,   23,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [   0,   13,   33,   34,   -1,   -1]])
```

For the lengths, the output should look something like this

```
LengthsResults
[5, 4, 6, 2, 4].
```

And here's an example output for picking a random non-pad number for each row.

```
randomNonPad
[84, 45, 0, 0, 34]
```

Edit:

I was looking at np.where, which lets you filter out parts of your numpy array on a conditional, and numpy random choice, which lets you pick a random number for an array. I'm not sure what to do with np.where though, it seems that you can change it to something, but I'm not sure what yet, or even if it's the right approach. For python, you could start with a list, and append it to any length, but for numpy you need to establish the array length ahead of time.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and explain why you weren't successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - this probably overlaps with @Mad's answer; I'll leave it in case the alternative explanation clears up some point of confusion.

```
In [32]: numList = [[0, 32, 84, 93, 1023, -1], [0, 23, 33, 45, -1, -1], [0, 10, 15, 21, 2
    ...: 4, 25], [0, 23, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0 , 13, 33, 34, -1, -1]] 
    ...: numArray = np.array(numList)                                                    
In [33]: numArray                                                                        
Out[33]: 
array([[   0,   32,   84,   93, 1023,   -1],
       [   0,   23,   33,   45,   -1,   -1],
       [   0,   10,   15,   21,   24,   25],
       [   0,   23,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [   0,   13,   33,   34,   -1,   -1]])
```

number of pads per row:

```
In [34]: np.sum(numArray==-1, axis=1)                                                    
Out[34]: array([1, 2, 0, 4, 2])
```

number of non-pad per row:

```
In [35]: np.sum(numArray!=-1, axis=1)                                                    
Out[35]: array([5, 4, 6, 2, 4])
```

I don't know if assuming the pad values are all at the end makes this any more efficient or not.  The sample's a bit small to make good timings.

picking a random non-pad from each row, the obvious first attempt is a row list comprehension:

```
In [40]: [np.random.choice(row[row!=-1]) for row in numArray]                            
Out[40]: [32, 0, 0, 23, 34]
```

Alternatively working from the lengths (above) (and assuming tail padding) we could pick a random index for each row:

```
In [46]: [np.random.choice(i) for i in Out[35]]                                          
Out[46]: [1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
In [47]: numArray[np.arange(numArray.shape[0]), [np.random.choice(i) for i in Out[35]]]  
Out[47]: array([93, 45, 21, 23, 13])
```

In hat tip to @Mad, `randint` accepts a list/array of range values, the `choice` comprehension can be replaced with:

```
In [49]: np.random.randint(Out[35])                                                      
Out[49]: array([3, 1, 2, 1, 1])
In [50]: numArray[np.arange(numArray.shape[0]), np.random.randint(Out[35])]              
Out[50]: array([ 0, 23, 24,  0,  0])
```

Answer (score 2):

The index of the negative number in the row, which is also the length of non-padded elements, is most simply gotten by

```
lengths = np.argmin(numArray, axis=1)
```

This assumes that the padding number is the same for all elements within the row. This won't work properly for rows with no negative numbers, so you can fix it with:

```
lengths[np.take_along_axis(numArray, lengths.reshape(-1, 1), axis=1).ravel() >= 0] = numArray.shape[1]
```

You can now use this information to generate an array of random indices into your rows:

```
indices = np.random.randint(lengths)
```

And apply the index to get the corresponding elements:

```
result = np.take_along_axis(numArray, indices.reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)
```

While cleaning up the `lengths` array is likely the faster option, a shorter expression might be something like

```
lengths = np.where(np.any(numArray < 0, axis=1), np.argmin(numArray, axis=1), numArray.shape[1])
```

Also, if your padding number is not a consistent negative number, you will need to replace `np.argmin(numArray, axis=1)` with either `np.argmax(numArray < 0, axis=1)`, or `np.argmin(numArray >= 0, axis=1)`, regardless of which approach you use to compute `lengths`.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7. I'm on mobile, so I'll test it out when I get a chance.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7. I made a mistake. You need `take_along_axis` rather than just `take`. That involves an extra `reshape`/`expland_dims`, but that's still cheaper than calling a `arange` for the equivalent fancy index.

Comment: I updated my post with the strategies I was attempting to use for a solution, I didn't get far with them. The new 2nd line results in `IndexError: too many indices for array`. It seemed like what you were trying to do is find where it was 0, and replace it with six? I tried `lengths[lengths ==0] =6` and it worked, but I'm guessing this has flaws, or you would have used this in the first place.

Comment: I'm looking at `indices = np.random.randint(lengths)`, which also gives an error. If `lengths` was a python list, I could use `indices = np.random.randint(0, lengths)`, but since its a numpy array and I can only use numpy, this does not work.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7. That wouldn't work unless your indices were strictly increasing and you never had a fully padded row. I'll debug when I'm off mobile. In the meantime, keep reading the docs and trying to figure it out. That's the best way to learn. It's why I try to write out the purpose of each step, so you can imagine what it *should* do, even if I have a bug. That being said, let me know if anything is unclear in the meantime.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7. I've fixed the issue. I suggest that you work on your debugging skills.